Is it possible to update dynamics features with Google play console internal sharing?
so I'm facing a issue where my application download and install or load (I don't know if It's the downloading and installing or my application loading the older version which is the problem) the older module instead of the new imported bundle.aab from Google play console. The update for modules can be for example, add new stuff, fix crashes or add code.older module version showing the notification bar
newer module version hiding the notification bar
public void splitInstallRequest1(LinkedList<Module> modules, SplitInstallManager manager) {
        if (modules == null || modules.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "No modules to install.");
            return;
        }

        Module module = modules.peekFirst();

        SplitInstallRequest request = SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder()
                .addModule(module.getModulePackage())
                .build();

        // Listener to handle state updates of module installation.
        listener = state -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener: state: " + state.status());
            switch (state.status()) {
                case SplitInstallSessionStatus.DOWNLOADING:
                    long totalBytes = state.totalBytesToDownload();
                    long progress = state.bytesDownloaded();
                    // Update your UI to show download progress here
                    updateProgressMessage("Downloading module: " + progress + "/" + totalBytes);
                    break;

                case SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLING:
                    updateProgressMessage("Installing module...");
                    break;

                case SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLED:
                    SplitInstallHelper.updateAppInfo(this);

                    if (module.getModuleAssetPackName() != null) {
                        moduleAssetManager.install(module);
                    }
                    modules.pollFirst();
                    if (!modules.isEmpty()) {
                        splitInstallRequest1(modules, manager);
                    }
                    updateProgressMessage("Module installed successfully");
                    break;

                case SplitInstallSessionStatus.FAILED:
                    updateProgressMessage("Failed to install module: " + state.errorCode());
                    break;

                case SplitInstallSessionStatus.REQUIRES_USER_CONFIRMATION:
                    try {
                        manager.startConfirmationDialogForResult(state, this,
                                USER_CONFIRMATION_CODE);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        };

        // Register the listener for state updates.
        manager.registerListener(listener);

        // Start the install request.
        manager.startInstall(request)
                .addOnSuccessListener(sessionId -> {
                    mySessionId = sessionId;
                    Log.i(TAG, "Installation session started successfully with ID: " + sessionId);
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(exception -> {
                    if (exception instanceof SplitInstallException) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error installing module: ", exception);
                        int errorCode = ((SplitInstallException) exception).getErrorCode();
                        splitInstallErrors(errorCode);
                    }
                });
    }

